# How can i add data from txt file to global array

Tags: python, arrays, readfile

I want to read data from a txt file and add it to an array that will be global.

my file has the following data:
`Sophia Emily Mary Linda Madison Susan Lily ...`

I want them in array

`name = [ 'Sophia', 'Emily', 'Mary', 'Linda', 'Madison', 'Susan', 'Lily', ...]`

it -> ... means that there is still n amount of data, eg it's thousands

someone advised me to use this

```
with open('dane.txt') as name:
    contents = name.readlines()
```

but i don't know how to convert it to global data named 'name'

Comment: You should really strive to avoid globals in the first place. Why can't this be a function, and if necessary, give it the [`@functools.cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache) treatment?

Comment: I want it to be global because many functions will refer to this array

Comment: You can still use a cached function for that. In general it's best to pass in dependent data into a function, not just magically pluck it out of the global space.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string separated by spaces, you can do this:

```py
contents = "Sophia Emily Mary Linda Madison Susan Lily"
name = contents.split(" ")
```

Full code:

```py
name = None

with open("dane.txt") as f:
    contents = f.read()

    name = contents.split(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't have arrays - it has lists.

Using globals is generally frowned upon. There's often a better way. Consider this:

```
from functools import cache

@cache
def get_names(filename):
    names = []
    with open(filename) as data:
        for line in map(str.strip, data):
            names.extend(line.split())
    return names
```

All we need to do is call *get_names()* with the path to some file that contains the names we're interested in. Providing the contents of that file don't change then second and subsequent calls to *get_names()* will not cause the file to be opened and read. It will simply return the cached list